# How to return a Promise after an XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, promise, xmlhttprequest, dynamics-365

I call the function enableButton in Dynamics 365 to enable/disable a button. I must return a Promise to the system. If I do a simple test function that returns a Promise this works fine, but I need to get a token and then an external call to a service to set true/false and then return the Promise. When I do this it does not work. Seems Dynamics never get the Promise from the function.

Here's my code(I have emitted a few details). I only call enableButton() in Dynamics.

```
function enableButton() {
    var params = getParams();
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "http://my.tokenendpoint.com");
    xhr.onload = function () {
        var token = JSON.parse(xhr.response).access_token;
        getExternalData(token, ssn);
    }
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(params);
}

function getExternalData(token) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var url = "http://example.com"
        var query = JSON.stringify(
            {
                "queryparams": true
            }
        );

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", url);
        xhr.onload = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    var hasExternalData = hasExtData(data[0]); //returns a boolean
                    resolve(hasExternalData);
                }
                else {
                    reject(xhr.statusText);
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = function (e) {
            reject(xhr.statusText);
        };

        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhr.send(query);
    });
}
```

I have rewritten the code using fetch, but I am not receiving the correct data in return to Dynamics.

If I test with a simple function like this in Dynamics it works:

```
function enableButton() { 
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                var test = true; 
                resolve(test); 
            }, 
            function (error) { 
                reject(error.message); 
                console.log(error.message); 
            } 
        ); 
    }
```

If I do like this it does not work:

```
function enableButton() { 
    fetch(accesstokenUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: <omitted params>
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (resJson) {
            return fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + resJson.access_token,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(
                    {
                        "queryparams": true
                    })
            });
        })
        .then(function (res) {
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {
         const hasDebtCase = getDebtCase(data);
              if (hasDebtCase) {
                return Promise.resolve(hasDebtCase);
            } else {
                return Promise.reject(data);
            }  
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        })
};
```

What is my problem here?

Comment: Don't use XMLHttpRequest, it's outdated long ago. Use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) instead, which returns a promise as you need.

Comment: See this page to see how to promisify a function: https://javascript.info/promisify

Comment: So enableButton should be a promise... Unclear what the promise is for since you do not use it.

Comment: I want the function enableButton to return the promise resolve/reject after the check hasDebtCase.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below article on how to return promise when using enable rule in Dynamics CRM.
https://ajitpatra.com/2019/12/11/d365-enable-rule-for-button-with-asynchronous-api-request-using-promise/?utm_campaign=Dynamics%20Weekly&utm_medium=email&utm_source=Revue%20newsletter

Please mark my answer verified if i were helpful

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it is better to use async/await with [fetch](https://javascript.info/fetch).

```
async function enableButton() { 
    const responseA = await fetch(accesstokenUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
                "access_token": "123"
        },
    });
   const responseAJson = await responseA.json();
   console.log("Response from the first fetch", responseAJson);
   console.log("Your Access Token", responseAJson.access_token);
   
   const responseB = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + responseAJson.access_token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(
            {
                "queryparams": true
            })
    });
    console.log("Response from the second fetch", await responseB.json());
    
    const hasDebtCase = getDebtCase(responseB.json());
    if (hasDebtCase) {
        return Promise.resolve(hasDebtCase);
    } else {
        return Promise.reject(data);
    }  
 }
```

Comment: I have not tried that approach. Thank you, I will try that.